# d3 pack layout circles overlapping after movement/size transitions

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js, transition, circle-pack

I have circles arranged with the pack layout, from a dataset which periodically updates the radii.

The code I started out with is this standard example for a bubble chart: http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4063269

[image]

Whenever the circle sizes change, they transition.  Often when circles grow, they move to overlap other circles. I don't want them to overlap each other.

I'm still pretty new to d3, have moved the code around a lot and tried everything I can think of, but no luck.

The function `makeBubbles` is passed raw Json (see below).

```
function makeBubbles(root){
  var diameter = $(window).width(),
      diameterh = $(window).height(),
      format = d3.format(",d"),
      color = d3.scale.category20();

  var bubble = d3.layout.pack()
      .sort(null)
      .size([diameter, diameterh])
      .value(function(d){return d.value; })
      .padding(1.5);

  var svg = d3.select("svg")
      .attr("width", diameter)
      .attr("height", diameterh)
      .attr("class", "bubble");

  var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
      .data(bubble.nodes(classes(root)).filter(function(d) { return !d.children; }),     function(d){  console.log(d); return d.className; });


  node.append("title")
      .text(function(d) { return d.className + ": " + format(d.value); });

  node.append("circle")
      .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.packageName); })
      .on("click", function(d) { window.location = d.url; })
      .attr("r", 0)
      .transition()
      .duration(1000)
      .attr("r", function(d) { return d.r; });

  node.transition().duration(1000).attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"; });

  node.enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "node")
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"; });

  node.exit().transition().duration(200).attr("transform", "scale(0.001)").remove();

  node.append("text")
      .attr("dy", ".3em")
      .style("text-anchor", "middle")
      .text(function(d) { return d.className.substring(0, d.r / 6); })
      .attr("opacity",0)
      .transition().duration(1000)
      .attr("opacity",1);

// Returns a flattened hierarchy containing all leaf nodes under the root.
  function classes(root) {
    var classes = [];

    function recurse(name, node) {
      if (node.children) node.children.forEach(function(child) { recurse(node.name, child);     });
      else classes.push({packageName: name, className: node.name, value: node.size, url: node.url});
    }

    recurse(null, root);
    return {children: classes};
  }

  d3.select(self.frameElement).style("height", diameterh + "px");
}
```

Data passed looks something like this (varying as the dataset is updated):

```
{"name":"bubbles","children":[{"name":"tourism","children":[{"name":"tourism","children":[{"name":"practical","children":[{"name":"ACCOMM","size":13,"url":"#"},{"name":"HIRE","size":2,"url":"#"}]},{"name":"activity","children":[{"name":"EVENT","size":6,"url":"#"},{"name":"TOUR","size":3,"url":"#"}]},{"name":"leisure","children":[{"name":"RESTAURANT","size":168,"url":"#"},{"name":"ATTRACTION","size":8,"url":"#"}]}]}]}]}
```

Comment: The key to this is to handle the update selection appropriately when updating, i.e. you do not need to append new circles, but update the existing ones. You can find more information in [this tutorial](http://mbostock.github.io/d3/tutorial/circle.html) for example.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem.

I slightly modified (mostly simplified) your code, and [here](http://jsfiddle.net/VividD/Y2H8e/3/) you can find working example.

My approach is not to use transformations. Without them, the code looks more readable and maintainable. So, I propose a simple solution, I hope you can use it in your case.

Label. transition is maybe not the best, but you can change it.

On jsfiddle, its impossible to integrate json files, so the data is inside javascript. In your code, you would need to handle loading json, but the core idea from my example can be applied without change.

The key function is:

```
function updateVis() {

    if (dataSource == 0)
        pack.value(function(d) { return d.size; });
    if (dataSource == 1)
        pack.value(function(d) { return 100; });
    if (dataSource == 2)
        pack.value(function(d) { return 1 +
                 Math.floor(Math.random()*501); });

    var data1 = pack.nodes(data);

    titles.attr("x", function(d) { return d.x; })
        .attr("y", function(d) { return d.y; })
        .text(function(d) {
            return (d.children ? "" : d.name + ": " + format(d.value));
        });

    circles.transition()
        .duration(5000)
        .attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
        .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; })
        .attr("r", function(d) { return d.r; });

    labels.transition()
        .duration(5000)
        .attr("opacity", 0) 
        .attr("x", function(d) { return d.x; })
        .attr("y", function(d) { return d.y; })
        .each("end", function(d){
            d3.select(this).text(function(d) {
                    return d.children ? "" : d.name.substring(0, d.r / 4);
                });
            d3.select(this).transition()
                .duration(1000)
                .attr("opacity", 1);
        });

};
```